# Handling custom error responses in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller

I am building a REST API using .net WEB API.

Here is a sample code

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        // GET api/values
        public Values Get(int ID, int userID)
        {
            return new Values(){};
        }
}
```

Now what I want to do is return a different class if userID is not in allowed userID list. I was thinking of throwing an exception, but after I considered it I don't think that would be a good idea. Reason for this is that process was handled with OK status.

Basically I would like to return a custom ErrorMessage object instead of Values object. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Throwing an exception is still valid. How about `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);`? This is equivalent to a 404 response.

Comment: Why not change the status code to 400? What does `Reason for this is that process was handled with OK status.` mean

Comment: @DavidG I want to create and return a custom class containing additional "error" information.

Comment: @John With additional information `throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound){ReasonPhrase = "Couldn't locate userID"});`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov depending on how you view the problem. I could go with status 400, but how custom can I make the Response Exception?

Comment: @DavidG what would be a difference between throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Couldn't locate userID")); and  throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { ReasonPhrase = "Couldn't locate userID" });

Comment: @DavidG first one throws exception and second one doesn't. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO throwing an exception is valid when the flow of your code encounters an abnormal situation.

If you still dont want to throw, you can create a wrapper class that describes your result:

```
public class ValueResponse
{
   public HttpStatusCode HttpStatus { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
   public Values Values { get; set; }
}
```

and return that object

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/values
    public ValueResponse Get(int ID, int userID)
    {
        // Send a valid response or an invalid with the proper status code
    }
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. I have overseen it